# Model Transformation

Tags: c#, linq, model

I have a data model with the following properties.

- Date
- Treatment Facility
- Weight

However, the client application database that accepts this data requires a daily allotment.  The current data model for the base application has recurring data, for instance.

```
Date: 01/19/2018
Plant Code: RC
Weight: 54,920

Date: 01/19/2018
Plant Code: RC
Weight: 90,740
```

So I need to transform that into a different model for this other application totaling the weight value of the fats, oils, and greases.  I've done the following, which works, but is there a better way?

```
var transformation = models.GroupBy(property => new
{
     property.Date,
     property.PlantCode
})
.Select(group => new HachWimsModel()
{
     Date = group.Key.Date,
     PlantCode = group.Key.PlantCode
     Total = group.Sum(property => property.Weight)
};
```

Comment: You could always use a third party library like 'AutoMapper' and then differentiate how to change it.  However I have never used it with groupby methods.  I assume it would work but may not.  Generally I would use it to separate a front end ViewModel from a server side Entity ViewModel for separation of concern.  But if it is a small app, what you are doing seems fine.  Just depends on end goals like most things in development.

Comment: @djangojazz Thank you for the reply, small console application that pulls data from SharePoint into this client application.